# Is there any benefit to dashing the enemies in the overworld

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-sparks-of-hope

*Mario+Rabbids: Sparks of Hope* features enemies walking around the overworld which you can walk into to start a battle. When moving towards these enemies you are prompted to press A to dash, which if done correctly gives an animation of them being thrown into the air before moving to the battle screen. Alternatively, if you are hit by the enemy it is your characters who are shown being thrown.

In many games, such as the *Paper Mario* series, launching attacks in the overworld would lead to some advantage in the battle, such as getting a free opening attack or determining who makes the first move. *Sparks of Hope* does not seem to have anything obvious like this, but is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no benefit to dashing the enemies rather than having them attack you to begin combat. I think the reason that there is no benefit is because even if the enemy attacks you, you can just flee from the battle, meaning if you did have a disadvantage, you could just flee and make sure you dashed them first next time.